# Adobe AIR issues with iOS 8 and poor performance

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, air, ios8, starling-framework

#### Problem Description:

We have two (distributed!) iOS apps built for Adobe AIR:

- One uses the pure native AS3/AIR capabilities (vector graphics, integrating swc's from Adobe Flash, etc.).
- Another one uses Starling and DragonBones as game/animation engines.

Upgrading our devices (for example, iPad 3) from iOS 7.1.2 to iOS 8.0.2, we encounter numerous bugs and performance decrease:

- Screen flickers to black every few seconds.
- MANY memory warnings that were not there before.
- Animations stop working after interacting with the UI - for example after MOUSE_UP event on any interactive display object, all the animations are skipped - MovieClips skip to last frame immediately.
- Animations get stuck in the middle if user interacts while they’re playing.
- Sound playing issues - sounds can work ok after launch, but then randomly stop and never come back. Sometimes though in some of the screens sounds won’t work at all.
- Sound recording (via normal Microphone.getMicrophone()) stops working at some point.

#### Environment:

All of the above are bugs discovered ONLY in iOS 8 and with different devices and different apps with different technologies (Starling / not).
Besides AIR SDK 15, problems happened also with AIR SDK versions 14, 13, and even 4.

Basically I can say that our apps are useless under iOS 8 and AIR SDK. We have other native apps that made the 7>8 transition with no problem, so it must be an AIR issue.

iOS 8 should work like it does under iOS 7.

Anyone also encountered these issues? any suggestions?

Here's also a bug report I posted in Adobe Bugbase system:

https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3835391

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please update your AIR SDK and re-compile it again.
Here is the link http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/air.html. Select your version.

Actual version is 15.0.0.302 from the Labs. It contain a lot of iOS8 fixes. I'm not sure if this can help but just try to do this.

Comment: Yep, just did it and it does solve most of the issues.
Very surprised how much change with that very recent .302 beta.
Thanks!